# How to create a function to split date and time from a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

How can I remove value before '_'  and show date and time in one row in TSQL Function?

Below is sample:

```sql
Declare @inputstring as varchar(50) = 'Studio9_20230126_203052' ;

select value from STRING_SPLIT( @inputstring ,'_')
```

Output Required: `2023-01-26 20:30:52.000`

Comment: I *assume* the value is *always* in the format `{Some String}_{yyyyMMdd}_{hhmmss}`?

Comment: *"but String length is not fixed "* This conflicts with your prior comment *"he format always is {Some String}_{yyyyMMdd}_{hhmmss}"*. Which is it? Is or isn't it always in the format `{Some String}_{yyyyMMdd}_{hhmmss}`?

Comment: No, there is no contradiction. ،Thank you for your Answer

Comment: There is; you initially state it's always in the format, and then state it's not, so which is it? If the `yyyyMMdd_hhmmss` isn't always the same length, what other formats can there be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[convert_to_date] (@inputstring NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS DATETIME AS
BEGIN 

        DECLARE @finalString varchar(50), @out varchar(100)

        SET @finalString = REPLACE ( (SUBSTRING (@inputstring, CHARINDEX('_', @inputstring)+1 , LEN(@inputstring))), '_', ' ')
                    
        --SELECT @finalString

        SET @out  =  LEFT (@finalString, 4) + '-'               
                    + SUBSTRING(@finalString, 5, 2) + '-' 
                    + SUBSTRING(@finalString, 7, 2) + ' '
                    + SUBSTRING(@finalString, 10, 2) + ':'
                    + SUBSTRING(@finalString, 12, 2) + ':'
                    + SUBSTRING(@finalString, 14, 2) + '.000'
            
RETURN  @out
END
```

Select Query

```
SELECT dbo.[convert_to_date] ('Studio54541659_20230126_203052')
```

Output

```
2023-01-26 20:30:52.000
```

Comment: Why return an `nvarchar(250)` when the value is clearly a date and time value?

Comment: yes you can use DATETIME too, let me correct it

Answer (score 2):

If we can *safely* assume that the value is always in the format `{Some String}_{yyyyMMdd}_{hhmmss}` then you can use `STUFF` a few times, firstly to remove the leading string up to the first underscore (`_`) character (using `CHARINDEX` to find that character), and then to inject 2 colon (`:`) characters. Finally you can `REPLACE` the remaining underscore with a space ( ), and then use `TRY_CONVERT` to attempt to convert the value to a `datetime2(0)`.

```sql
DECLARE @inputstring varchar(50) = 'Studio9_20230126_203052';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),REPLACE(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@inputstring,1,CHARINDEX('_',@inputstring),''),14,0,':'),12,0,':'),'_',' '));
```

Note that this *doesn't* give the value you state you want in your question (`2023-01-26 20:05:52.000`) , but I assume this is a typographical error, and that the `05` for minutes should be `30`.

Comment: Yeah I edit my Output Required, this is a typographical error.

Comment: *"Larnu ,but String length is not fixed."* I don't understand your point here. The only part I assume is fixed is the `yyyyMMdd_hhmmss` part, and you **explicitly** stated it's always in that format in the above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282882/how-to-create-a-function-to-split-date-and-time-from-a-string-in-sql/75282957?noredirect=1#comment132842587_75282882); are you saying it *isn't* always in the format `{Some String}_{yyyyMMdd}_{hhmmss}`? If so, you need to correct your question.

Answer (score 1):

This will tolerate "somestring" in the format of "somestring_YYYYMMDD_HHMISS" being variable in length.

```
Declare @inputstring as varchar(50) = 'Studio9_20230126_203052' ;

 SELECT  DateAndTime = CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(v2.DT,14,0,':'),12,0,':'),9,1,' '))
        ,Identifier  = LEFT(@inputstring,v1.Pos1-1) --Included this because I know how people are :D --Comment out if not wanted.
        ,Original    = @inputstring --Original string just for checking. Comment out when happy.
   FROM (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',@inputstring)))v1(Pos1) --Position of first Underscore
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@inputstring,v1.Pos1+1,50)))v2(DT) --String after first Underscore
;
```

Output looks like this and you end up with a DATETIME datatype. Comment out what you don't want for columns in the return.
[image]

I'll let you have some of the fun by converting it into an iTVF (inline Table Valued Function).  Remember that any function that contains a "BEGIN" is ultimately going to be a part of a performance issue so make sure it's an iTVF :D

EDIT: Crud... I've gotta remember to scroll down.  @Lamu already posted the same thing but it's probably better and fast if you just want the time and not the identifier I included.